# How to decipher the machine codes from x86 ASM?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

I have following 2 lines from listing (x86 ASM):

```
0009 66| BB 00000014        mov EBX, (type Tabl1)*2
000F 67| 8D 00000000 R      lea DL, A2[EBX])
```

Could you explain me what is a meaning of each part of machine code (the left part of line)?

Comment: Google "Intel Instruction Encoding"

Answer (score 1):

```
0009 66| BB 00000014
```

0009 is an offset in the program
66 is an operand size prefix
BB is an instruction opcode
00000014 is a 32 bit address displacement

```
000F 67| 8D 00000000
```

000F is an offset in the program
67 is an address size prefix
8D is an instruction opcode
00000000 is a 32 bit address displacement